# How to change font size which can't be picked from 'Font' setting

Tags: fonts, appearance

I installed Macbuntu for my Ubuntu 10.04. The theme is nice and cool.

I want to change the font size to larger. I open the 'Appearance' preference, I find Macbuntu changed the font of system to 'Lucida Grande'.

[image]

However I can't find the 'Lucida Grande' in the font list, so I can't change the font size from 9 to 12.

[image]

Could anybody give me a hint how to change the font size for 'Lucida Grande'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug, you should probably file a bug report.

But to answer your question, you could do this graphically (using `gconf-editor`) but the font settings are spread all over in the gconf database, so the fastest way is to use the command line utility `gconftool` to change these settings:

**Application font:**

```
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/font_name --type=string "Lucida Grande 12"
```

**Document font:**

```
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/document_font_name --type=string "Lucida Grande 12"
```

**Desktop font:**

```
gconftool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/desktop_font --type=string "Lucida Grande 12"
```

**Window title font:**

```
gconftool --set /apps/metacity/general/titlebar_font --type=string "Lucida Grande 12"
```

**Fixed width font:**

```
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/monospace_font_name --type=string "Lucida Console 12"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the fonts that come with the MacBuntu package to the .fonts/ directory located in your home directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where Macbuntu put the font file.

Comment: Well, as I do know, there's a "font" directory that comes with the MacBuntu package.

Comment: I find those fonts after copying them into ~/.fonts. Thanks.